# Basement bathroom

Tags: plumbing

Here is a mystery Ife asked a few people, and so far no real answer.  I have three drain pipes sticking out of the slab in the basement.

[image]

Each one is a different distance from the wall.  Each one is 5 inch in diameter.  The realtor told me that when is house was built in '53, the owner wanted a basement bathroom.  So I am hoping these are shower, sink, and toilet drains.  Is that what these are?

Do I get one of those cameras and see where each goes?  Make sure they are intact?  See if one is connected to the dry vent of the other toilet?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, get a camera with a super long feed or get a pipe inspecting plumber. You not only want to make sure they're connected you also want to make sure what diameter they're connected to.

5" indicates they're a slab spacer & not the actual piping. The shower should have a trap beneath the floor, if not you'll have to either breakout the floor to put one in or have to raise the shower floor or tub to put one in.

Once that's figured out, you're halfway there on the plumbing. Drains are great, but you need Supplies more importantly if you want the drains to do anything. Opening the ceiling will hopefully reveal capped Supplies. If not then you'd have to run new Supplies to the area.

Comment: Don't forget you'll need a vent pipe too.

Comment: Thanks & yep the plumber will need to determine if or how to vent. They may just go with an Air Admittance Valve if the group isn't near enough to the stack or go with a side-wall vent.

Comment: Looking down each pipe, they are leading in the same direction as my upstairs shower and toilet.

Comment: Great & I expect they're proper & attached. But, be sure you won't be creating a sinkhole under the house. Maybe the laundry comes over here or a bar or a kitchenette get tied-in. Does the shower one seem trapped, did you pour a cup or 10 (if the pipes are 5" across) of water down it to see that it remains & doesn't just drain away..."maybe" into the soil? You're very fortunate, hopefully in the ceiling too, but be sure.